# Make Divs on both sides of another div expand to the edge of the container

Tags: html, css

Best way to demonstrate what I want is to show it:
[image]

I want the left and right `div` to expand to the left and right edge of the container div automatically.

It can be done with `Javascript` and with `flex` but I'm wondering is there is another way that supports IE9+ (`flex` is IE11+)

I created this [live demo](http://jsbin.com/tojubopa/2/edit?html,css,output) (click "Run with JS") with a dynamically changing center `div` (since the "real life" problem doesn't have a static size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `display: table-cell` would make it easy for you.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/VytTX/1/***

*HTML*:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div id="left" class="inner"></div>
    <div id="center" class="inner">...</div>
    <div id="right" class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
body { width: 100%; }
div.outer {
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: rgb(12, 34, 43);
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
div.inner {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 20px; width: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(212, 234, 143);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that like this :

An example: http://codepen.io/srekoble/pen/rugxh (change the variable of the center width $width)

It's a sass file for a variable usage:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.outer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: rgb(12,34,43);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}

div.inner {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  min-width: 20px;
}

$width: 50%;

#center {
  width: $width;
  background: red;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: ( 100% - $width ) / 2;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
body
{
   background: #0B222A;
}
.outer
{
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background: #D3EA8F;
   margin: auto;
}
.inner
{
   width: 60%;
   height: 300px;
   background: #D3EA8F;
   border-left: solid 10px #0B222A;
   border-right: solid 10px #0B222A;
   margin: auto;
}

</style>


<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```